# Converting vector<Point2f> of openCV into Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point> of C#

Tags: c#, c++, generics, opencv

I want to convert a vector of point in OpenCV (vector) into a list of C# points (Collections::Generic::List) at my C++ project.
I wrote some code like below, but it didn't work:

```
vector<Point2f> oldPoints;
Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point>^ points;
for (int i = 0; i < oldPoints.rows; i++)
 {
     points -> Add(Windows::Point(oldPoints.at<Point2f>(i,0).x,oldPoints.at<Point2f>(i,0).y));
 }
```

Does anybody can help me? Where I did wrong?
I couldn't find a good answer for my question; any help or clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oldPoints` is `std::vector`, but you work with it as with `cv::Mat`. The correct code is:

```
vector<Point2f> oldPoints;
Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point>^ points 
    = gcnew Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point>();
for (size_t i = 0; i < oldPoints.size(); i++)
{
    points->Add(Windows::Point(oldPoints[i].x, oldPoints[i].y));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the List:

```
Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point>^ points = gcnew Collections::Generic::List<Windows::Point>();
```